How to disallow using the different quotes (’) and only allow (') with ESLint?
There're are quotes that are different from the usual ones used in coding.
I want to disallow using ’ and “ and only allow ' and "
How can I do that with ESLint?
VS Code already flags that the quote is different, but I want to have it in ESLint so I can fail builds if the different quote is used.


Using them where, exactly? They're already not valid as string delimiters in JavaScript, so ESLint would fail to parse them as such. If you mean within strings, perhaps you need something like unicorn/string-content.
